# Null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have the following code:

```
decimal? a = 2m;
decimal? b = 2m;
decimal c = a ?? 1m * b ?? 1m;
```

Since both `a` and `b` have been filled in, I'm expecting `c` to give me the result of **4**.

However, the result I get is **2**, in which case `b` is taken as **1** instead of **2**.

Does anyone know what is the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression works as:

```
decimal c = a ?? (1m * b) ?? 1m;
```

As `a` has a value, you get that.

Answer (score 5):

group the value condition if you want to get the value of `4`

```
decimal c = (a ?? 1m) * (b ?? 1m);
```

your current syntax is evaluated as

```
decimal c = a ?? (1m * b ?? 1m);
```

and the reason why you get the value of `2` (*as for `a`*)

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal c = a ?? 1m * b ?? 1m;
```

Equals to:

```
if (a != null)
    c = a
else
    ...
```

In your case `a` is not null and has the value of `2` so this is the result.